# msc + xelatex = 

Tags: xetex, msc

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

to `xelatex` results in

```
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:770/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 64
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

on the tty.  Five years ago it all went well, however. Who is the culprit and what to do? We know that the used parts (`xelatex` and `msc`) are dead, but are they already *that* much dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a change in ghostscript that disabled some things by default for a less trusting world, your example runs for me in texlive 2021 with

```
xelatex  -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" file.tex
```

the "unsafe" xdvipdfmx configuration was added in recent texlive to address exactly this issue.