# PSTricks \rput command seems not to work in xelatex

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pstricks-add

With the following document compiled with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,6)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(10,6)
\pnode(2,2){C}
\psdot(C)
\rput(C){NOTWORKING!!!!}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I always get the text 'NOTWORKING!!!!' at the origin (0,0) instead of the specified point. My xelatex --version: 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian).

I cannot find this issue looking up google. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeXSX! For me, this code runs fine with `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: `lualatex` as well as `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` works, but `xelatex` gives a Ghostscript error, `/invalidfileaccess` with operand stack `(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)`. (TeXlive 2021) `--shell-escape` doesn't make a difference. Check the log file for error messages.

Comment: this is a change in ghostscript see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629915/1090  `xelatex --shell-escape -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg"` works on this example

Comment: @Bernard you have an old ghostscript I would guess.

Comment: I have ghostscript v9.50 so this apply: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516100/problem-with-rput-command-with-xelatex-and-pstricks/628328#628328

I have made a work-around by using pdflatex + --shell-escape + \usepackage[pspdf={-dDELAYSAFER}]{auto-pst-pdf} (with [pspdf={-dDELAYSAFER}] for opacity).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The version coming with MiKTeX is indeed 9.25, but I have installed independently `gs 9.55`, and I use xelatex with the  `--shell-escape` switch.

Comment: There was a bug in `xdvipdfmx` years ago. I suppose that you have such an old version with this bug, which was fixed later. Try to update, because TL 2019 is really really old ...